# Use NGINX to replace body from proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, openresty, lua-ngx-module

I am new to `openresty/nginx` and am trying to replace the body the comes from an earlier call to proxy_pass with code like this:

```
body_filter_by_lua_block {
  ngx.arg[1] = '{"count"' .. ":2}'
  ngx.arg[2] = true
}
```

I had originally, not had the line for `ngx.arg[2] = true`, but I would get back the body twice (does that mean the body I'm replacing has 2 chunks?). I added in the `ngx.arg[2] = true` line and now the output from the request looks good. When I deploy the `nginx` file, the service looks good for a few requests then the `nginx` requests start to hang. Is the correct/best practice for replacing the response body? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `body_filter_by_lua_block`:

`ngx.arg[1]` is current chunk of response body.

`ngx.arg[2]` is end-of-file flag. I often see this flag set in separate `body_filter_by_lua_block` invocation, when `ngx.arg[1]` is `nil`.

It is why you saw your string twice.

EOF flag above has read/write access, so if you set it to `true` it means just throw away any remaining chunk data.

Changing body content works fine for me, even did some performance testing, never see hangs while using this.

PS: Don't forget to include `header_filter_by_lua_block { ngx.header.content_length = nil }` if you change the body.

Also there may be some tricks with compressed content.